# Splice function adds extra elements in array

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

When I use splice function it inserts the point but makes duplicates copies of last element of the array.

```
    for(indexpoint=0;indexpoint<intpoints.length;indexpoint++)

    { 


            temp.points[indexpoint].x = intpoints[indexpoint].x+this.x;

            temp.points[indexpoint].y = intpoints[indexpoint].y+this.y;


    }

    const point:Point = new Point();
    point.x = (intpoints[2].x+intpoints[3].x)/2+this.x;
    point.y = (intpoints[2].y+intpoints[3].y)/2+this.y;

    temp.points.splice(3,0, point);
```

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't happen.

I tried this:

```
var a:Array = new Array(new Point(0,0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(0, 2));
var p:Point = new Point(0, 3);
a.splice(3, 0, p);
trace(a);
```

This traces correctly : (x=0, y=0),(x=0, y=1),(x=0, y=2),(x=0, y=3)

Can you try tracing the temp.points array before the splice is called?